# Including PHP in .JS file

Tags: javascript

Before anyone says this should be on the Wordpress Stackexchange, please read through as this is a JS query and not a Wordpress query.  I am trying to get a path to the Wordpress theme in to a JS file so I don't have to include the full path, would usually use `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` in the template files but obviously we are working in a JS file here.

I have found a forum post that says to use the following before the JS file is called for:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var template_url = "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>";
// -->
</script>
```

and then in the JS file put `template_url` but this just puts 'template_url' in the middle of the path.

The line this is to go in is:

```
$(this).prev().css({ backgroundImage : 'url(template_url/images/icons/menu-divider.png)' });
```

How can I please get the full path to be called in this line of JS?

Many thanks
Adrian

Comment: @Quentin how is that a duplicate? The question title may be similar but the actual question is not.

Comment: Yes, totally different type of question?!

Comment: @Halcyon — The question is asking how to use the variable `template_url` in a string, and the attempt looks like: `'url(template_url/images/icons/menu-divider.png)'`

Comment: I am asking how I am meant to put the variable 'template_url' in to the file to make it get the actual template URL as I don't know Javascript.

Comment: @Adrian, if you mean in the js file the answer is you can't. You can't use PHP in an external js file.

Comment: @Ionut I know I cant' I said this in the question, please read properly, hence i've defined the variable in PHP before the JS file is loaded.

Comment: And now you want to put that variable in a string … which is what the duplicate question is all about.

Comment: Looking at the page @Quentin linked my question to, would this work?
`$imageurl = template_url + "images/file.png";`

Comment: $(this).prev().css({ backgroundImage : "url(<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>template_url/images/icons/menu-divider.png)" });

Comment: No, because you want to end up with is  `{ backgroundImage : 'url(SOMETHING/images/icons/menu-divider.png)' }` not `$imageurl = "SOMETHINGimages/file.png";`

Comment: @Ionut — No. That line is in a .js file. It won't be passed through the PHP compiler.

Comment: @Quentin I was thinking along these lines:
`$imageurl = template_url + "/images/file.png";`
`$(this).prev().css({ backgroundImage : 'url($imageurl)' });`

Comment: $(this).prev().css({ backgroundImage : 'url(' + template_url + '/images/icons/menu-divider.png)' });

Comment: @Adrian — So now you are trying to put a variable called `$imageurl` into the string `'url($imageurl)'`, which gives you the same problem just with a different variable name.

Comment: I know vey little about javascript, I just need to know how to turn the 'var template_url' in to the actual template URL in the JS file.

Comment: @Adrian — You now know all the JavaScript you need to know to solve this problem. You just need to apply a little logic to it.

Comment: Thank you @Ionut I tried your suggestion and this worked.

Comment: You welcome @Adrian. Glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

Using this function returns what you're looking for
`get_template_directory_uri()`

So, do this

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var template_url = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>";
// -->
</script>
```